# internal server error when post html data with ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am testing what happens on an an html page input field if a user enters javascript and then it is posted to another page.

```
<script>alert("Hey!")</script>
```

Prior to posting the data entered by the user I url encode it so it looks like this:

somepage.aspx?message=%3Cscript%3Ealert(%22Hey!%22)%3B%3C%2Fscript%3

posting this via ajax causes an internal server error 500 and the page load event is never fired.

If the user enters less than "<" or greater than ">" everything works fine, so is there a 'safe' way to send data like this?  I thought uri encoding it would be enough.

This looks like a response to a cross scripting attack detection, I could encode the data (hexify, base64) but I thought html encoding would do it.

Again, the problem is with html in the arg, the page load on test4 is never hit and ajax returns "Internal Server Error".

EDIT2: Here is a simple example that reproduces the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test 3</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv">
    </div>
    <script>
        el = $("#myDiv");
        //var arg = "Hello handsome :>"; //ok
        //var arg = "< div >"; //ok
        //var arg = "< and >"; //ok
        var arg = "<div>"; //fail
        arg = encodeURIComponent(arg);
        $.ajax({ url: "test4.aspx?data=" + arg,
            success: function (result) {
            el.html(result);
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            el.html("<div>" + c + "</div>");
        }
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Public Class test4
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        targetDiv.InnerHtml = Request("data")
    End Sub
End Class

<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div runat="server" id="targetDiv">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show the actual code where you make the ajax request?

Comment: This is just passing data to a page on the url, it works except when the text is html or an html fragment (as far as I can tell from trial and error), the text <div> or <div>some text</div> fail, but "here is < and >" works.

Comment: You need to set up a web method on your aspx page, better yet, set up an asmx page.

Comment: @Bindrid better still a WCF webservice or Web API. ASMX has been legacy for about 10 years

Comment: Dumb on my part - I was confusing uriEncoding with htmlEncoding. This fix is: arg = encodeURIComponent(htmlEncode(arg)); Then htmlDecode(arg) on the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

If you use AJAX, your Page will not be refreshed and Page_Load will not be run.
Execute the code as follows:
This code works fine

```
var promise = test();
promise.success(function (data) {
  alert(data.d);
  $("#targetDiv").html(data.d);
 });

function test(){
   el = $("#myDiv");
    //var arg = "Hello handsome :>"; //ok
    //var arg = "< div >"; //ok
    //var arg = "< and >"; //ok
    var arg = "<div>"; //fail
    arg = encodeURIComponent(arg);
    return $ajax({type: "POST", url: "test4.aspx/update", data: '{cod: "' + arg+ '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
        failure: function (response) {
            var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText); alert("Message: " + r.toString());
        }
    }, null);}
```

and server side with c#

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string update(string cod)
    {
      //do.....
      return cod+DateTime.Now.ToString();
     }
```